# Is this conclusion via rules of inference correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Use rules of inference to show:

1. ∀x(P(x) → Q(x)) premise
2. ∀x(Q(x) → R(x)) premise
3. ¬R(a) premise
4. ¬P(a) conclusion

I have a lot of trouble with these sort of questions and was wondering if I did this correctly. Usually I have no idea which rules to use and it feels like I just need to try them randomly until they work.

> 1) ∀x(P(x) → Q(x))        **premise**
>
> 2) P(a) → Q(a)        **Universal instantiation (1)**
>
> 3) ∀x(Q(x) → R(x))        **premise**
>
> 4) Q(a) → R(a)        **Universal instantiation (3)**
>
> 5) P(a) → R(a)        **Hypothetical syllogism (2,4)**
>
> 6) ¬R(a)              **premise**
>
> 7) ¬P(a) **Modus tollens (5,6)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this looks perfectly good to me.

Comment: I've been fighting with the derivation of modus tollens all day! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818272/alternative-rule-for-negation-introduction

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the formal name of the different silogism but you can write

$$\forall x(P(x)\implies R(x))\tag{1}$$

To see this clearly you can prove it via "if $x\in P(x)$ then..." and use the notation:

$$(A\implies B)\iff(\lnot A\lor B)$$

Then if $\lnot R(a)$ and $(1)$ is true then $\lnot P(a)$ must be true.