# Is double negation introduction an axiom of intuitionistic logic or can it be derived?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

If I have a rule for negation introduction...

```
Rule (NegationIntroduction,ProofByNegation)
  Premises
    P=>Q, P=>⌐Q
  Conclusion
    ⌐P
```

...then it seems to me that I can derive the rule for double negation introduction:

```
Rule (DoubleNegationIntroduction)
  Premises
    P
  Conclusion
    ⌐⌐P
  Proof
    Suppose
      ⌐P
    Hence
      P
    ⌐P=>P

    Suppose
      ⌐P
    Hence
      ⌐P
    ⌐P=>⌐P

    ⌐⌐P by NegationIntroduction
```

There are two places where I can see that the reasoning might be faulty. Firstly, the assumption $⌐P$ when $P$ is given as a premise. However, can you not assume anything for the purposes of an argument even if the contrary is known to be true? Secondly, the resulting implication $⌐P=>P$. However, I know that intuitionistically as well as classically we have $A=>(C=>A)$. I have read [Propositional Logic - Can you Derive $C \to A$ from $A$ alone, given the introduction rule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804660/propositional-logic-can-you-derive-c-to-a-from-a-alone-given-the-introdu) for example, so I'm pretty sure that this is okay.

Comment: The derivation of the rule about halfway down the page here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Derived_Inference_Rules suggests this derivation is fine. In particular, they use the same 'trick' as me, namely repeating the outer premise to derive the implication $⌐P=>P$. The contrasting implication $⌐P=>⌐P$ is not derived, however I assume the rule for negation introduction that they employ is simpler. This is not intuitionistic logic, but I think that at least in this case the principles are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $A\to \neg \neg A$ is intuitionistically valid, and your proof looks correct.

Many presentations of intuitionistic logic consider $\neg A$ to be an abbreviation for $A\to \bot$, and in that case $A\to\neg\neg A$ is
$$ A\to((A\to\bot)\to \bot)$$
which is just an instance of the generally valid
$$ A\to((A\to B)\to B) $$

Comment: Many thanks, good to get that one cleared up.

Comment: If Np abbreviates Cp0, then CCpNqCCpqNp is an instance of CCpCqrCCpqCpr.